# Sync simulink with workspace variable update

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

I need to process some signals using simulink. Such signals are obtained in real time from an external simulator, and the values are stored in arrays (that increment dimensions at each time step, when a new value is retrieved) in the matlab workspace. Now, I would like to "reroute" these arrays to simulink, such that whenever a new value is added to the signal array, simulink reads it, performs its computations and plots the result in a scope.
Is there any way to do this? Is it possible to advance a simulink simulation via an external trigger (i.e., "check if new value added")?

Comment: What do you consider real-time (1 millisecond, 1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour)?  Does your model have state, or is it just a stateless calculation?  Do you want to just increment the model one step at a time as new data arrives, or can it be run from time zero, with the whole data set, each time?  Is there a requirement for MATLAB to tell Simulink to run when new data arrives, or can Simulink "poll" MATLAB to see if new data is available?  Can Simulink be used to get the new data directly, or does it have to come via MATLAB?

Comment: @PhilGoddard with real-time I intend that the data streams arrives as soon as the data is available (each 50 ms in the external simulator, for that matter). And yes, my idea is  exactly to just increment the model one step at a time as new data arrives

Comment: MATLAB and Simulink are non-real time applications - you have zero chance of achieving what you are trying to do within a 50ms time frame.  You'll need to use Simulink directly, using something like `External Mode` with [Simulink Desktop Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-desktop-real-time.html) or [Simulink Real-Time](https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-real-time.html).